# Finding the natural frequency

Tags: transfer-function

I am trying to figure out the natural frequency and the time constants of a transfer function. Ignoring the numerator and using the denominator of the second order characteristic equation:

$$s^2+2\zeta\omega_ns + \omega_n^2 $$

where $$\zeta=0.5, $$ $$\omega_n^2 = \frac{100}{\tau_1},$$

and  $$2\zeta\omega_n = \frac{1+100\tau_2}{\tau_1}.$$

$$s^2+\frac{1+100\tau_2}{\tau_1}s + \frac{100}{\tau_1} $$

How do you find the value of natural frequency without knowing the tau constants?  Is it even possible? It seems I have two equations with three unknowns? EDIT: Am looking for an actual number.

Comment: Are you looking for a number or for an expression?

Comment: Am looking to calculate an actual number.

Comment: Then something is missing here.

Comment: Show the whole question, if you know that damping factor that could help

Comment: Without the values of \$\tau_1\$ and \$\tau_2\$ , I don't see how you can get a numeric value for \$\omega_n\$. There isn't enough information. I'm assuming \$\tau\$ is some time constant for a system, spring system, RC/RL circuit, etc. But perhaps the question simply wants you to solve for \$\omega_n\$ in terms of \$\tau_1\$ and \$\tau_2\$ and in that case you need to set a system of equations. You may be able to substitute your equations and have only \$\tau_1\$ but that's as far as you can probably get.

Comment: Substituting \$\zeta=0.5\$ you can reduce your problem to **1 equation with 2 unknowns**: \$ \sqrt(\frac{100}{\tau_1}) = \frac{1+100\tau_2}{\tau_1} \$. So, Without the values of \$\tau_1\$ **OR** \$\tau_2\$ I neither see see how you can get a numeric value for \$ \omega_n \$

Answer (score 1):

> > How do you find the value of natural frequency without knowing the tau constants? Is it even possible?

No.
The problem is that there is **1 equation with 2 unknowns**. You need to know either \$\tau_1\$ or \$\tau_2\$ as shown below.

Substituting \$\zeta=0.5 \$ in
$$ 2\zeta\omega_n = \omega_n = \frac{1+100\tau_2}{\tau_1} $$

and using 
$$\omega_n^2 = \frac{100}{\tau_1}$$

gives 1 equation with 2 unknowns:

$$ \sqrt { \frac{100}{\tau_1} } = \frac{1+100\tau_2}{\tau_1} $$
or
$$10 \sqrt { \tau_1 } = 1+100\tau_2 $$

If you know one of the unknowns, you can find rest using:

$$ \tau_1 = \frac{ (1+100\tau_2 )^2}{100} $$

$$ \tau_2 = \frac{ 10\sqrt{ \tau_1 } - 1 }{100} $$

and
$$\omega_n = \sqrt { \frac{100}{\tau_1} } =  \frac{100}{1+100\tau_2} $$